# jtables (jquery api) with struts2 as model part

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery, jquery-jtable

i am developing an ajax based CRUD tables application using jsp/struts and hibernate, i am not able to retrieve the json data in my java class using struts ,json data is sent from jsp using ajax call

Index.jsp page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'TODO TABLE',
            selecting : true,
            multiselect : true,
            selectingCheckboxes : true,
            paging : true,
            sorting : true, 

            actions : {
                listAction : '<s:url action="listaction"/>',
                createAction : '<s:url action="createaction"/>',
                updateAction : '/updateaction',
                deleteAction : '/deleteaction'
            },

                fields : {
                    studentId : {
                        title : 'Student Id',
                        width : '30%',
                        key : true,
                        list : true,
                        edit : false,
                        create : true
                    },
                    name : {
                        title : 'Name',
                        width : '30%',
                        edit : true
                    },
                    department : {
                        title : 'Department',
                        width : '30%',
                        edit : true
                    },
                    emailId : {
                        title : 'Email',
                        width : '20%',
                        edit : true
                    }
                },


            });
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
```

And in my java class  i am trying to recover the json data in my java class but the values are null

```
public String create() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("inside create");
        record = new Bean();

        record.setStudentId(studentId);
        record.setName(name);
        record.setDepartment(department);
        record.setEmailId(emailId);

        try {
            // Create new record
            String name=record.getName();
            System.out.println(name);
            String dept=record.getDepartment();
            System.out.println("dep");
            System.out.println(dept);
            result = "OK";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "ERROR";
            message = e.getMessage();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return Action.SUCCESS;  
    }
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>  


<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="json-default">


 <action name="*action" class="com.programmingfree.controller.FullStack"
            method="{1}">


        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>

        </interceptor-ref>


            <result type="json">/index.jsp</result>
</action>



    </package>
```

i looked over the data sent

[data sent from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaD8X.png)

but in java class

[but in java class the values are coming as null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6e5l.png)

Comment: Where did you use ajax?

Comment: jtable is already developed plugin using jquery api(http://www.jtable.org/),in the plugin ajax is used